# GDB and corefiles what causes "Failed to read a valid object file image from memory."

Tags: linux, gdb, coredump

On a rather old Linux system, I am unable to get core dumps that the gdb can read afterward. The kernel version is 3.8.13 and the libc version is 2.3.4. `ulimit -c` is set to unlimited and `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` points to a valid writable file location. When I abort any process (`kill -6 PID`) it produces a core file at the location specified. However when trying to read the core file later using `gdb -core filename` I always get the error message "Failed to read a valid object file image from memory." What is the exact meaning of this message and what causes it? I also set all the bits to 1 in `/proc/<pid>/coredump_filter` but it did not help.

Further, I figured out that when I attach gdb to a process and then create a core file from gdb using the command `generate-core-file` it produces a core file that I can read into gdb without getting this warning. I tried to load the core file into gdb version 6.3.50 and version 7.10-1ubuntu.

Comment: How did you compile the executable? Did you use `gcc -g` ?

Comment: Tried both with and without symbols. Gdb should be able to load the core file in both cases without `-g` you just don't get to see the symbols.

Answer (score 4):

> However when trying to read the core file later using `gdb -core filename` I always get the error message "Failed to read a valid object file image from memory."

You can very likely ignore that warning.

What are you trying to do *after* `gdb -core filename`? You *probably* want `gdb ./a.out core` (which would produce the same warning, but should give you a usable GDB session).

> what causes “Failed to read a valid object file image from memory.”

Some versions of GDB do not understand the [VDSO](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/08/linux-gate/), which appears in the loader list of shared objects, but isn't one, and issue the warning above. This warning is safe to ignore.

Comment: It seems like GDB is producing an error; and not a warning. Perhaps I am reading it wrong, or maybe GDB just redefined the meanings of error and warning.

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether this is an error or a warning. Did you give GDB the executable file to go with the core or not? Without the executable file, core is pretty useless.

Comment: ooOHHH The Mammoth from Russia wrote back :) Thanks for your answer. I know that I also need to provide an executable preferably with symbols to get a useful session.